# How to pass a variabile to a LayoutTemplate loaded in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, variables, user-controls

I have a "for cycle" that creates a ListView and load the LayoutTemplate (3 times).

I pass the "j" value (the number of the cycles) to the usercontrol of the LayoutTemplate.

```
   for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
                   ......
            lv = new ListView();
            lv.ID = "LVprogram" + j;
            lv.DataSourceID = ds.ID;
            lv.ItemPlaceholderID = "rlt$itemPlaceholder";

                        ...then I declare the ItemDataBound, LayoutCreated, ItemTemplate....



                        // I put the "j" value in a global variable (App_Code)
                        // in order to pass it to the user control:

            marmar.j = j;

                        // I load the usercontrol
            lv.LayoutTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/rassegne/rlt.ascx");
            PHprograms.Controls.Add(lv);
            lv.DataBind();
```

The usercontrol codebehind (rlt.ascx.cs):

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (marmar.j == 1)
            sx = "_a";
        else if (marmar.j == 2)
            sx = "_b";
                 .....
```

The problem: the marmar.j variable has ALWAYS value "3", the final value of the "for cycle", like the usercontrol is loaded after the "for cycle".

If before loading the template it had value "1", in the usercontrol it has value "3".

I don't understand the logic of it.

---

many thanks for trying to help me.

Here's rlt.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="rlt.ascx.cs" Inherits="rlt" %>

        <div class="program rounding">

            <!-- h2 -->
            <asp:FormView id="FV" runat="server" DataSourceID="QueryShowH1" RenderOuterTable="false">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h2 class="program"><span class="rounding"><%# Eval(marmar.jolly) %></span></h2>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:FormView>

            <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="program">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </ul>

            <m:pager ID="pager" runat="server" size="10" showcount="false" />
        </div><!-- id="program1" -->
```

marmar.jolly is another global variable whose value depends on "j" (it's definited in the aspx.cs)
m:pager is a nested usercontrol.

Here's rlt.ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class rlt : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    string sx;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (marmar.j == 1)
            sx = "_a";
        else if (marmar.j == 2)
            sx = "_b";

        pager.pagesuffix = sx;
        pager.idsuffix = marmar.j;
    }
}
```

---

Just in case, for complete information, here's the ASPX code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

public partial class rassegne : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    int i;
    int j;
    int pgm;
    protected int psx;
    ListView lv;
    string a1;
    string a2;
    bool autore;
    bool regista;
    bool sceneg;
    PlaceHolder phli;
    public object di;
    string[] matrice;
    AccessDataSource ds;
    string df = "~/App_Data/marmar_be.mdb";
    string pm = "IDshow";
    string fullpm;
    Panel pnc;
    HtmlGenericControl h4;
    string ept;

    string[] autori1 =
    {
        "autore",
        "regista",
        "sceneggiatore",
        "marca"
    };

    string[] autori2 =
    {
        "oautore",
        "autore",
        "oregista",
        "regista",
        "osceneggiatore",
        "sceneggiatore"
    };

    string[] q =
    {
        "program1",
        "program2",
        "tvr"
    };

    void parametrizza(AccessDataSource a)
    {
        QueryStringParameter qp = new QueryStringParameter();
        qp.Name = pm;
        qp.QueryStringField = fullpm;
        qp.Type = TypeCode.Int32;
        a.SelectParameters.Add(qp);
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString == null)
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx", true);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //marmar.incostruzione();


        fullpm = marmar.pf + pm;
        QueryShowH1.DataFile = df;
        QueryShowH1.SelectCommand = "SELECT IDrassegna, rassegna, status, inizio, fine, programma1, programma2 FROM rassegne WHERE IDrassegna = @" + pm;
        parametrizza(QueryShowH1);


        vh1();



        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {

            ds = new AccessDataSource();
            ds.ID = "QueryProgram" + j;
            ds.DataFile = df;
            ds.CancelSelectOnNullParameter = false;
            ds.SelectCommand = File.ReadAllText(this.Server.MapPath("~/sql/" + q[j - 1] + ".sql"));
            parametrizza(ds);
            Page.Controls.Add(ds);


            lv = new ListView();
            lv.ID = "LVprogram" + j;
            lv.DataSourceID = ds.ID;
            lv.ItemPlaceholderID = "rlt$itemPlaceholder";

            if (j == 1)
            {
                lv.ItemDataBound += LVprogram1_ItemDataBound;
                lv.LayoutCreated += new EventHandler(LVProgram1_LayoutCreated);
            }
            else if (j == 2)
            {
                lv.ItemDataBound += LVprogram2_ItemDataBound;
                lv.LayoutCreated += new EventHandler(LVProgram2_LayoutCreated);
            }
            else if (j == 3)
            {

                if (Request.QueryString[fullpm] != "9")
                    lv.Visible = false;

                lv.ItemDataBound += LVprogram3_ItemDataBound;
                lv.LayoutCreated += new EventHandler(LVProgram3_LayoutCreated);

            }

            lv.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/rassegne/rit.ascx");

            if (j == 2)
                psx = j;
            else
                psx = 1;

            marmar.jolly = "programma" + psx;
            marmar.j = j;
            lv.LayoutTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/rassegne/rlt.ascx");
            lv.EmptyDataTemplate = null;
            PHprograms.Controls.Add(lv);
            lv.DataBind();



            //Response.Write(marmar.j);
            //Response.Write(marmar.jolly);

            /*
            FormView fv = (FormView)lv.FindControl("FV");

            if (fv != null)
            {
                fv.ID = "FV" + j;


                if (fv.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
                {
                    if (j == 2)
                        psx = j;
                    else
                        psx = 1;

                    di = DataBinder.GetDataItem(fv.ID);
                    marmar.jolly = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "programma" + psx).ToString();
                }

                fv.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("~/moduli/rh2.ascx");

            }


            */
        }

    }

    void vh1()
    {


        if (ShowH1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
        {
            PlaceHolder PHH1 = (PlaceHolder)ShowH1.FindControl("PHH1");
            di = DataBinder.GetDataItem(ShowH1);
            string iniziot = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "inizio").ToString();
            string finet = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "fine").ToString();
            string rassegnat = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "rassegna").ToString();

            HtmlGenericControl h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1");
            h1.InnerHtml = rassegnat;
            PHH1.Controls.Add(h1);

            HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            p.Attributes.Add("class", "year");
            PHH1.Controls.Add(p);

            Literal inizio = new Literal();
            inizio.Text = iniziot;
            p.Controls.Add(inizio);


            if (iniziot != finet)
            {
                Literal ndash = new Literal();
                ndash.Text = "&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;";
                p.Controls.Add(ndash);

                Literal fine = new Literal();
                p.Controls.Add(fine);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finet as string))
                    fine.Text = finet;
                else
                    fine.Text = "in corso";
            }
        }

    }


    void vdata()
    {
        Panel pnd = new Panel();
        phli.Controls.Add(pnd);

        Literal ltd = new Literal();
        ltd.Text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "data", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").ToString();
        pnd.Controls.Add(ltd);
    }


    void opera(string o)
    {
        Literal op = new Literal();
        op.Text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, o).ToString();
        h4.Controls.Add(op);
    }

    void punto(string c)
    {
        Literal punto = new Literal();
        punto.Text = ".";
        punto.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c as string);
        h4.Controls.Add(punto);
    }


    void quo(string v)
    {
        Literal quo = new Literal();
        quo.Text = v;
        quo.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ept as string);
        h4.Controls.Add(quo);
    }

    void titolo()
    {


        h4 = new HtmlGenericControl("h4");
        phli.Controls.Add(h4);

        if (pgm == 1)
            opera("opera");

        else if (pgm == 2)
        {
            string sst = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "sottoserie").ToString();
            string stagt = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "stagione").ToString();
            string numt = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "numero").ToString();
            string segt = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "segmento").ToString();
            ept = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "episodio").ToString();

            opera("opera");

            Literal ss = new Literal();
            ss.Text = "&nbsp;" + sst;
            ss.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sst as string);
            h4.Controls.Add(ss);

            Literal hash = new Literal();
            hash.Text = "&nbsp;#";
            hash.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(numt as string);
            h4.Controls.Add(hash);

            Literal stag = new Literal();
            stag.Text = stagt;
            h4.Controls.Add(stag);

            punto(stagt);

            Literal num = new Literal();
            num.Text = numt;
            h4.Controls.Add(num);

            punto(segt);

            Literal seg = new Literal();
            seg.Text = segt;
            seg.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(segt as string);
            h4.Controls.Add(seg);

            Literal colon = new Literal();
            colon.Text = ": ";
            colon.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ept as string);
            h4.Controls.Add(colon);

            quo("&ldquo;");

            Literal ep = new Literal();
            ep.Text = ept;
            ep.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ept as string);
            h4.Controls.Add(ep);

            quo("&rdquo;");
        }

        else if (pgm == 3)
            opera("tvrip");

    }


    void condizioni()
    {
        if (pgm == 1)
        {
            autore = ((i == 0) || (i == 3));
            regista = (i == 1);
            sceneg = (i == 2);
        }
        else if (pgm == 2)
        {
            autore = ((i == 0) || (i == 1));
            regista = ((i == 2) || (i == 3));
            sceneg = ((i == 4) || (i == 5));
        }
    }

    void doppi(int k)
    {
        a1 = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, matrice[k]).ToString();
        a2 = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, matrice[k] + "2").ToString();
        condizioni();

        Literal etic = new Literal();
        etic.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a1 as string);
        pnc.Controls.Add(etic);

        Literal primo = new Literal();
        primo.Text = a1;
        primo.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a1 as string);
        pnc.Controls.Add(primo);

        Literal virgola = new Literal();
        virgola.Text = ", ";
        virgola.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a2 as string);
        pnc.Controls.Add(virgola);

        Literal altri = new Literal();
        altri.Text = a2;
        pnc.Controls.Add(altri);

        marmar.acapo(a1, pnc);

        if (autore)
            etic.Text = "di ";

        if ((regista) || (pgm == 3))
            etic.Text = "Diretto da ";

        if (sceneg)
            etic.Text = "Scritto da ";
    }

    void vautori()
    {

        if (pgm == 3)
        {
            doppi(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < matrice.Length; i++)
            {
                doppi(i);
            }
        }


    }

    void corpo()
    {
        pnc = new Panel();
        phli.Controls.Add(pnc);

        if (pgm == 1)
        {
            string spt = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "specifiche").ToString();

            Literal sp = new Literal();
            sp.Text = spt;
            pnc.Controls.Add(sp);

            marmar.acapo(spt, pnc);
        }

        vautori();

        if (pgm != 2)
        {
            string punt = (string)DataBinder.Eval(di, "puntata").ToString();

            Literal pun = new Literal();
            pun.Text = punt;
            pnc.Controls.Add(pun);

            Literal ord = new Literal();
            ord.Text = "&ordf;";
            ord.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(punt as string);
            pnc.Controls.Add(ord);

            Literal puntata = new Literal();
            puntata.Text = " puntata";
            puntata.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(punt as string);
            pnc.Controls.Add(puntata);
        }

    }



    void popola()
    {
        vdata();
        titolo();
        corpo();
    }





    protected void LVprogram1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        pgm = 1;
        matrice = autori1;
        marmar.lvdi = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        phli = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.Controls[0].FindControl("PHli");
        di = e.Item.DataItem;
        popola();
    }

    protected void LVprogram2_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        pgm = 2;
        matrice = autori2;
        marmar.lvdi = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        phli = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.Controls[0].FindControl("PHli");
        di = e.Item.DataItem;
        popola();
    }

    protected void LVprogram3_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        pgm = 3;
        matrice = autori1;
        marmar.lvdi = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        phli = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.Controls[0].FindControl("PHli");
        di = e.Item.DataItem;
        popola();
    }

    void layout()
    {
        //remove the layout template
        lv.Controls.RemoveAt(0);



        //recreate it
        Control newLayoutContainer = new Control();
        lv.LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(newLayoutContainer);
        var userControl = newLayoutContainer.Controls[0];
        userControl.ID = "rlt";
        lv.Controls.Add(newLayoutContainer);

    }


    void LVProgram1_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        layout();
    }

    void LVProgram2_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        layout();
    }

    void LVProgram3_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        layout();
    }

}
```

The ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Rassegne" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/marmar.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="rassegne.aspx.cs" Inherits="rassegne" %>




<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <style type="text/css">

        p.year
        {
            margin: 0 0 30px 0;
            font-size:1.2em;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
        }

        /* INTEGRARE */
        div.program
        {
            max-width:500px;
            margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
            padding:20px;
            background-color:#DDD9C4;
        }


        h2.program
        {
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
            font-size:larger;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:left;
        }

        h2.program span
        {
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px;
            background-color:orange;
        }

        ul.program li
        {
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-bottom:0;
        }

        ul.program > li:last-child {border-bottom: 1px solid white;}

        li.even {background-color:#FFFF8B;}

        li.odd {background-color:#EDE080;}

        h4 {margin:0;}

    </style>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="content" runat="server">

    <script>
        window.onload = showsubnav('subnav2');
    </script>




    <!-- h1 -->

    <asp:AccessDataSource
        ID="QueryShowH1"
        runat="server"
        CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>

    <asp:FormView runat="server" id="ShowH1" DataSourceID="QueryShowH1" RenderOuterTable="false">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PHH1" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>





    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PHprograms" runat="server" />





    <!-- programma1 -->







    <!-- programma2 -->






    <!-- TVR -->





</asp:Content>
```

By the way, in the aspx.cx how do I set the properties of an usercontrol loaded by LoadTemplate?

Many thanks again,
M.

Comment: If you _don't understand the logic of it_ how are you going to understand the answer? Besides the presented code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you call lv.DataBind(), Page_Load of your user control still does not get called. The call to this method takes place in a later stage of the page lifecycle.

What you need to do is find an other way of passing your value to the user control other than using a global variable. For example, if you could introduce a property in your user control codebehind and call

```
userControl.SomeProperty = j; // instead of marmar.j = j;
```

before calling

```
lv.DataBind();
```

your user control would render correctly. I cannot provide an exactly working code because I do not know about your full user control codebehind. It would be helpful if you posted full code for rlt.ascx.cs.